# Валидация параметров модели, которая не наследуется от ActiveRecord::Base в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

Добрый день

Как сделать валидацию параметров модели, которая не наследуется от ActiveRecord::Base в Ruby on Rails?

Что и где по этой теме почитать можно?

Спасибо

Comment: Валидация в моделях http://rusrails.ru/active-record-validations
Вы можете определить в абстрактной модели нужные правила и в дочернем классе дополнять новыми. Какой вопрос такой и ответ ) Ваш кэп.

Comment: @Invision а проверка валидации осуществляется только при .new и .create ?

Comment: Не обязательно. Воспользуйтесь методом @you_object.valid?

Comment: @Invision а как мне object создать, если для абстрактного класса .new и .create  "cannot be instantiated" ?

Comment: Так-так-так, тут сейчас начнётся разброд и хаос. Вы что имеете в виду под абстрактным классом? ActiveRecord-овскую модель, которую нельзя инстанцировать? Или то, что написано в вопросе после правки @MAXOPKA (которая, на мой взгляд, совершенно безосновательна)?

Comment: @D-side мы с мадам пообщались за пределами SO, выяснилось, что под понятием "абстрактный класс" - имелся ввиду класс, который не наследуется от ActiveRecord::Base. Вот я и поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать модуль для валидаций от Rails.
Почитать здесь: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html